# VBA procedure returns results only up to a certain date

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, export

everyone. I have a procedure that extracts certain data on a daily basis from a large table and then pastes this data to an excel file. The source table contains about 2 million records(starting from 01.10.2015 up to 09.09.2016) and growing at a pace of 220k records per month. The below procedure extracts successfully the data I need only up to the middle of June, 2016. From that point on, it cannot extract any data. Running a regular query does show that the data is there. Opening the table also shows the same result - data is available up to 09.09.2016). I would think there is some other problem with the code, but it does work correctly on another table. It works on this one as well, but cannot think of a reason why it won't find records past the middle of June 2016. I indexed the date field, which is my parameter for extracting records, but that didn't help. Any help and suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanks for your time. Here is my code:

```
Dim xl As Excel.Application
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim xs As Excel.Worksheet
Dim rng As Excel.Range
Dim c_range As Excel.Range


Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim strsql As String

strsql = "SELECT tblTraderExecutions.exec_id, tblTraderExecutions.exec_date, tblTraderExecutions.exec_time, tblTraderExecutions.empty, tblTraderExecutions.exec_string, tblTraderExecutions.internal_order_id, tblTraderExecutions.trading_account, " & _
"tblTraderExecutions.trading_account, tblTraderExecutions.operation_bg, tblTraderExecutions.empty, tblTraderExecutions.empty, tblTraderExecutions.symbol, tblTraderExecutions.symbol, tblTraderExecutions.price, tblTraderExecutions.quantity, " & _
"tblTraderExecutions.currency, ROUND(tblTraderExecutions.total_comm,2), tblTraderExecutions.empty, Round((tblTraderExecutions.quantity * tblTraderExecutions.price),2), Round((tblTraderExecutions.quantity * tblTraderExecutions.price),2), " & _
"tblTraderExecutions.trade_broker, tblTraderExecutions.contra, tblTraderExecutions.accept_broker FROM tblTraderExecutions " & _
"WHERE [exec_date] = [start_date] ORDER BY [tblTraderExecutions].[exec_id]"
Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set qdf = dbs.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, strsql)
qdf.Parameters("start_date").Value = Forms!frmPropReports!txtDate
Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset

Set xl = New Excel.Application
xl.Visible = True
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("D:\mpuls\trader_executions_export.xlsx")
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("DNEVNICI")
Set rng = ws.Range("a8")
rng.CopyFromRecordset rst

Set c_range = ws.Range("c8:c65000")
c_range.NumberFormat = "h:mm:ss;@"

rst.Close
qdf.Close
Set qdf = Nothing

Set rst = Nothing
Set dbs = Nothing
```

Comment: Could it be because you wish to process more than 1 million rows and Excel can only store (on any given sheet) no more than 1,048,576 rows? Maybe June 2016 is where Excel reaches the 1 million limit?

Comment: To @Ralph's suggestion, can you place `rst.MoveLast` and
`MsgBox rst.RecordCount` to see how many records the recordset is holding?

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the ` ADODB.Recordset.GetRows()` method to get an array of the data that you can write to the worksheet.

Comment: The query gets the data for one day only, with 220k records per month that's in the magnitude of 10k records per day, so it's a long way from 1 million.

Comment: @Selim: So your query gets n records for `start_date` < "middle of June", and zero records for later dates? -- To make sure it's not a problem with the parameter datatype, add `PARAMETERS start_date DateTime;` before your SELECT query.

Comment: To @nbayly - added rst.movelast and message box with rst.recordcount; it turns out that the query does extract the correct number of records for any given date; that means the problem comes from pasting the data into excel;

Comment: To @Ralph - I actually extract records only for a single day, which is as pointed below is in the range of 10k records; this number shouldn't be a problem for Excel

Comment: To @Andre - seems like the query is getting the records, since I was able to to do several correct record counts; pasting in Excel seems to be the problem;

Comment: Interesting... What exactly happens for a day where it doesn't work? The Excel sheet stays completely empty? Is there a runtime error? Make sure you don't have `On Error Resume Next` somewhere before your code, if in doubt, add `On Error Goto 0` before the Excel part starts.

Comment: @Andre - it just opens the excel template without any records in it

Answer (score 0):

first of all I'd like to thank everybody who contributed. 
My database was created on Access 2016 and I was running it on another pc, with Access 2013. This is where it was returning records only to a certain date. After moving it to a pc with Access 2016, it worked as expected, but was running excel only on the background with all applicable records in the exported file. At that point I moved the line xl.Visible = true below the line xl.workbooks.open. That worked like a charm.